# c++ output formatting issues

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gedit

i know this might sounds trivial to all of you, what i'm trying to do here is to format the layout.

```
    X     Y     Z    Dist. Fr Origin
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[  -9,   -9,   -9]   15.589
[ -99,  -99,  -99]   171.473
[-999, -999, -999]   1730.320
[   3,    3,    3]   5.196
[  23,   23,   23]   39.837
[ 123,  123,  123]   213.042
```

This is something that i would like to display.

I'm using an ostream operator that looks something like

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const Point& d)
{
    os << "["
       << d.x
       << ", "
       << d.y
       << "]"
       << d.distances;

    return os;
}
```

I have tried using setw, setprecision(3) for the decimal place but it isn't working.

```
Point.cpp: In function ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Point&)’:
Point.cpp:9: error: ‘setw’ was not declared in this
```

I hope someone can help me out. Thanks.

Comment: Please show line 9 in Point.cpp. I'm guessing you're missing std:: in front of setw.

Comment: Please don't show us the code that works. Show us a short, complete program that fails. See http://SSCCE.ORG for more information.

Comment: Check out the `right` manipulators at: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip

Answer (score 2):

If you see e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) you see that you need to include the `<iomanip>` header file.

Also, if you are not doing `using namespace std;` in your code (which I recommend you don't do) then you need the prefix it with `std::` like `std::setw`.